# Skip if conditions when a flag is false

Tags: java

I have several independent if conditions and in each condition i will evaluate a boolean variable value either true or false.

if the boolean variable value gets false in the first if condition then how can i skip the rest of all conditions.

```
private static boolean isRecommended(Fruit fruit) {
    boolean isRecommended = true;

    if(fruit.weight > 2){
        isRecommended = false;
    }
    if(!"red".equals(fruit.color)){
        isRecommended = false;
    }
    if(!"sweet".equals(fruit.taste)){
        isRecommended = false;
    }
    if(!fruit.isPerishable){
        isRecommended = false;
    }

    return isRecommended;
}
```

if the first if() condition is executed then is it possible to return the value. I know in the loops we can use `continue` keyword to skip the remainder of the loop execution. How can we achieve something similar here.

**Update:**

i do not mean exactly on the first if() condition, if any of the if() condition is executed then what is best way of skipping the rest of the conditions like continue does in loop

Comment: Why not use if-else if - else construct?

Comment: extends your bracket from that and incase of false use break statement.

Comment: Get rid of your `isRecommended` and return false from your ifs.

Comment: Why do you need to skip the rest of the conditions? Is it because you have a performance bottleneck that you need to eliminate, or do you sometimes get the wrong result?

Comment: sorry, i dont mean exactly on the first if() condition, if any of the if() condition is executed then what is best way of skipping the rest of the conditions like continue does in loop

Comment: edit the question properly...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
return fruit.weight <= 2 
    && "red".equals(fruit.color) 
    && "sweet".equals(fruit.taste)
    && fruit.isPerishable;
```

Answer (score 9):

For a general solution you could use `else if`:

```
if(fruit.weight > 2){
    isRecommended = false;
}
else if(!"red".equals(fruit.color)){
   //etc...
}
```

But in your specific example you can just use boolean logic:

```
return !(
   fruit.weight > 2 ||
   !"red".equals(fruit.color) ||
   !"sweet".equals(fruit.taste) ||
   !fruit.isPerishable
);
```

You could use your IDE to refactor the logic of this expression by applying [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). Most decent IDEs can do this for you with a few keystrokes.

Comment: You could De Morgan that boolean logic; IMO it looks confusing this way.

Comment: You could do, but then you would probably get it wrong like [this guy did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12752595/61974). Humans are *not designed* for doing De Morgan logic in their head. Write it in the way  (in the OP's opinion) is most logical **then get your IDE to do the De Morgan inversion for you**.

Comment: This makes me think to much.  I personally would avoid doing it this way, just like I avoid using unless($a && $b) in Perl.

Comment: @NullUserException My initial error pointed by Mark was when I tryed to copy OP's logic. Once I saw the essence of the problem (i.e. what is a recommended fruit for OP), it was clear and I fixed it. I find that in my version the intent is much more visible.

Comment: @dystroy: I'm not saying your version is less readable. I'm saying that humans shouldn't do the De Morgan conversion when the IDE has a feature that does exactly this for you automatically and never gets its wrong.

Comment: @dystroy FWIW [AmitD](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12752597/revisions) got it wrong too, but fixed it after/as I posted a comment on it. So Mark might have a point.

Comment: @MarkByers You're right in that we shouldn't do this conversion. But my solution isn't to let an IDE do it but to get back to the intent. For me speed of coding is much less relevant than speed of reading/fixing/maintaining (personal opinion).

Comment: FWIW I also upvoted Jonas answer which while a little more verbose, it seems to suit the OPs needs fine, keeps his "black list" approach rather than converting it to a "white list", and is still readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 8):

You can condense it like this, by using multiple return statements that will return early and skip the rest.  For added brevity I also removed the unneeded curly braces.

```
private static boolean isRecommended(Fruit fruit) {
    if(fruit.weight > 2)
        return false;
    if(!"red".equals(fruit.color))
        return false;
    if(!"sweet".equals(fruit.taste))
        return false;
    if(!fruit.isPerishable)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of removing "unneeded" curly braces. What if in the future someone decides to add a statement before one of these returns (eg: a log)? No syntax error will be produced (although it might complain about dead code) and now you have a mess in your hands.

Comment: @NullUserException: I agree, not everyone is. I used to be against it, but I have found that it makes it more readable because it is smaller and doesn't make it more prone to introducing errors.  In addition Robert Martin argues for the elimination of unneeded curlies in his book Clean Code as well.  Not that I agree with him on everything, but I do on this.

Comment: To me, it's not whether it's more errorprone or not, but that the IDE's autoformatting ruins brace formatting anyway; and consistent autoformatting is good for version control.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg I use NetBeans and have yet to see its autoformatting ruin my braces. But then I've adapted my style to that suggested by Sun/Oracle, which I assume is what NetBeans uses in its autoformatting.

Answer (score 6):

> if the first if() condition is executed then is it possible to return
>   the value.

Isn't that just it?

```
if(fruit.weight > 2){
    return false; // etc.
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: sorry, i dont mean exactly on the first if() condition, if any of the if() condition is executed then what is best way of skipping the rest of the conditions like `continue` does in loop

Comment: Ah, I figured you would extrapolate from my suggestion to Robert Hanson's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12752626/58668).

The general answer: use any control flow operator which is suitable for the task.  Another solution is do { ... } while (0), and then break when you have the answer; a third solution is to use exceptions.

Both are overkill for the problem at hand, though, so I'd go with the return-based one.

Answer (score 5):

The tests will stop at the first not verified.

```
private static boolean isRecommended(Fruit fruit) {
    return 
            fruit.weight <= 2
            && "red".equals(fruit.color)
            && "sweet".equals(fruit.taste)
            && fruit.isPerishable
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just write

```
return isRecommended;
```

inside your ifs. return can be used multiple times.

Comment: it thows the compile time error "This method must return a result of type boolean"

Comment: @KaipaMSarma.. At the end of all the if- blocks, you need to return a value .. `return true`.. i.e replace your `return isRecommended` currently with `return true`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `return false` in your first conditional.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to `return` within the `if` blocks, rather than setting a value. However, that's not exactly scalable, and `return`ing within the blocks increases code complexity.

The complicated, but more flexible answer, is to create an `interface` that allows you to implement custom logic.

```
interface RecommendationFilter<T>
{
    boolean recommend(T item);
}
```

And then, in some implementation, one can use a bunch of generically loaded `RecommendationFilter`s to loop through.

```
class FruitChecker
{
    private final Set<RecommendationFilter<Fruit>> filters = ...;

    public boolean isRecommended(Fruit fruit)
    {
        boolean recommended = true;

        for (RecommendationFilter<Fruit> filter : filters)
        {
            if ( ! filter.recommend(fruit))
            {
                recommended = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return recommended;
    }
}
```

This idea scales up pretty well, and it enables some pretty interesting implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the rest of the `if` statements in an `else` statement:

```
private static boolean isRecommended(Fruit fruit) {
    boolean isRecommended = true;

    if(fruit.weight > 2){
        isRecommended = false;
    } else {
        if(!"red".equals(fruit.color)){
            isRecommended = false;
        }
        if(!"sweet".equals(fruit.taste)){
            isRecommended = false;
        }
        if(!fruit.isPerishable){
            isRecommended = false;
        }
    }

    return isRecommended;
}
```

p.s. I highly recommend using spaces rather than tabs for indenting. Tabs often do not port to other editors or environments they way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution, that is the usage of label blocks with break statement. Below is the code

```
private static boolean isRecommended(Fruit fruit) {
    boolean isRecommended = true;

    labelA:
    {
        if(fruit.weight > 2){
            isRecommended = false;
            break labelA;
        }
        if(!"red".equals(fruit.color)){
            isRecommended = false;
            break labelA;
        }
        if(!"sweet".equals(fruit.taste)){
            isRecommended = false;
            break labelA;
        }
        if(!fruit.isPerishable){
            isRecommended = false;
        }
    }
    return isRecommended;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static boolean isRecommended(Fruit fruit) {
    while(true)
    {
      boolean isRecommended = true;

      if(fruit.weight > 2){
          isRecommended = false;
          break;
      }
      if(!"red".equals(fruit.color)){
          isRecommended = false;
          break;
      }
      if(!"sweet".equals(fruit.taste)){
          isRecommended = false;
          break;
      }
      if(!fruit.isPerishable){
          isRecommended = false;
          break;
      }
    }
    return isRecommended;
}
```

Comment: best way to skip all subsequent if conditions :)

Comment: if you want to avoid infinite looping during all false..use int i = 0; while(i<1){ //your if statements; i++;